# Can't connect to WebSocket server over wss:// (ws:// works), and no debug information

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, certificate, websocket

I have a website on `example.com`, and a WebSocket server on `example-websocket-server.com`.

Each have an SSL certificate so that I can access them from `https://`

I am using the websocket server as a websocket server for all the other websites, including `example.com` (there are more websites). However the `wss://` connection fails (`ws://` works).

The websocket server uses Laravel-Websocket as the server and it asks for a path to the PEM certificate: https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/ssl#configuration:

> ```
> /*
>  * Path to local certificate file on filesystem. It must be a PEM encoded file which
>  * contains your certificate and private key. It can optionally contain the
>  * certificate chain of issuers. The private key also may be contained
>  * in a separate file specified by local_pk.
>  */
> ```

So for that PEM certificate I used the same certificate as the `https://` certificate I am using on IIS

However I have a few issues - the certificate I am using on IIS was a `.pfx` file, with a given password string.

In order to create the PEM file used for the websocket server's `wss` connection, I first exported the `.pfx` to the PKCS7 file (`.p7b`), and then used OpenSSL to convert it to a `.cer` file. When I change the extension from `.cer` to `.pem` the file content look like that:

```
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----
[..long string..]
-----END PKCS7-----
```

(I tried using the file both as a `.cer` and `.pem` just in case)

But now the `wss://` fails, and there is no debug information so I have no idea what is the cause. And in my case it can be multiple:

1. I am using the wrong certificate
2. The conversion I did from the `.pfx` to the `.cer`/`.pem` is wrong
3. There is cross-origin restriction on my app side (Laravel) and that's the problem because the websockets server and the website are on different URLs (but less likely because it works with `ws`)
4. Some configuration for WSS in IIS (Although normal `ws://` connection worked)
5. PKCS7 is not compatible and I need PKCS12?

Or other thing I did not think of yet